# NodePort exposed Port connection refused

Tags: node.js, docker, kubernetes, yaml, dockerfile

Following a tutorial on Kubernetes and got stuck after the logs look fine, but the port exposed doesn't work : "Connection Refused" using Chrome / curl.

Used a yaml file to power up the service via NodePort / ClusterIP.

posts-srv.yaml - Updated

```js
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: posts-srv
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: posts
  ports:
    - name: posts
      protocol: TCP
      port: 4000
      targetPort: 4000
      nodePort: 32140
```

posts-depl.yaml - Updated

```js
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: posts-depl
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: posts
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: posts
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: posts
          image: suraniadi/posts
          ports:
            - containerPort: 4000
```

```
$ kubectl get deployments
NAME         READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
posts-depl   1/1     1            1           27m
$ kubectl get services
NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1       <none>        443/TCP          27h
posts-srv    NodePort    10.111.64.122   <none>        4000:32140/TCP   21m
$ kubectl get pods
NAME                          READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
posts-depl-79b6889f89-rxdv2   1/1     Running   0          26m
$ kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"19", GitVersion:"v1.19.7", GitCommit:"1dd5338295409edcfff11505e7bb246f0d325d15", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-01-13T13:23:52Z", GoVersion:"go1.15.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"darwin/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"19", GitVersion:"v1.19.7", GitCommit:"1dd5338295409edcfff11505e7bb246f0d325d15", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-01-13T13:15:20Z", GoVersion:"go1.15.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

Comment: Please don't include pictures of text or links to pictures of text. Include the relevant logs and YAML source *in your question*, formatted as a code sample (read the editor help for more information on properly formatted code).

Comment: Thank you, @larsks! Reediting now.

Comment: @larsks hopefully now should be fine! Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: What's the actual URL you're trying to connect to?  If you `docker run -p 4000:4000 suraniadi/posts` the same image in a non-Kubernetes environment, can you connect to it?

Comment: Did you expose port 4000 in Dockerfile? In deployment you should have `containerPort: 4000` as well.

Comment: @DavidMaze yes, I was able to connect to that from the sh.

Comment: @quentino I added it to my posts-depl.yaml, but still it's not working. The app is listening on 4000. I try to access: localhost:32140 and get connection refused.

Comment: @DavidMaze I try to connect to localhost:32140, after I set my nodePort as in the updated config file.

Comment: From where?  (`localhost` is very context-dependent.)  What Kubernetes installation are you using?

Comment: I go to that address from chrome. I use a mac, Kubernetes installed via Docker Desktop. Added the logs for versions.

Comment: Did you get anywhere with a solution?  I have exact same issue on Minikube on Windows.

Answer (score 2):

For structural reasons, it's better to specify the nodePort in your service yaml configuration file or kubernetes will allocate it  randomly from the k8s port range (30000-32767).
In the ports section it's a list of ports no need, in your case, to specify a name check the [nodePort_docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#nodeport) for more infos.
This should work for you :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: posts-srv
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: posts
  ports:
    - port: 4000
      targetPort: 4000
      nodePort: 32140
      protocol: TCP
```

To connect to the nodePort service verify if any firewall service is up then  verify that this port is enabled in your VMs : (centos example)

```
sudo firewall-cmd  --permanent --add-port=32140/tcp
```

Finally connect to this service using any **node IP** address (not the CLusterIP, this IP is an INTERNAL-IP not accessible outside the cluster) and the nodePort : <node_pubilc_IP>:<nodePort:32140>

Comment: Tried exactly as you were suggesting. I use a mac so the port should be open, firewall is off by default. I tried to hit localhost:32140 and it didn't work.

Comment: Another issue is I don't have any external IP address showing anywhere. `$ kubectl get nodes -o wide` still shows none for the external IP address.

Comment: nodePort does not configure an external IP node,  this APi-resource will just bind traffics of the service to a specific port in all your  cluster nodes check it by running $ kubectl get svc

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Hajed answer(upvoted without any doubts) I would like to again mention [Type NodePort Documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#nodeport), especially next part:

> Note that this Service is visible as **`<NodeIP>:spec.ports[*].nodePort`**
> and `.spec.clusterIP:spec.ports[*].port`

IN order your `nodePort` service works as expected, please do not forget to use `spec.ports[*].nodePort`

Your service should be

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: posts-srv
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: posts
  ports:
    - port: 4000
      targetPort: 4000
      nodePort: 32140 #you can use here 30000-32767 range. Just not forget to open firewall rule for this exact port further
      protocol: TCP
```

Answered few days ago [similar nodePort question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67383375/9929015) - check it also, maybe will be helpful in future.

Comment: Tried exactly that. The localhost:32140 keeps sending connection refused.

Comment: I also updated the initial post with more logs for versions and the files as you recommended.

Comment: @AdrianSurani did you resolve this? Following the same tutorial

Comment: @bonijad383 No, I skipped it back then.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using **minikube**, you should try this to get the ip

```
minikube ip
```

after that try with the port from your yaml file:

```
curl http://<id_above>:<port>
```

It should work.